# "heritage" in Makefile

Tags: makefile, multiple-makefiles

I'm looking a way to overload parts of a Makefile **A** to another one **B**, hence extending **A**.

For instance we have the following makefile **A**:

```
TEXT="AHAHA"

default: after-default

before-default: 
    echo "BEFORE DEFAULT"

default: before-default
    echo ${TEXT}

after-default: default
    echo "AFTER DEFAULT"
```

I want to reuse it in a new Makefile **B** like this:

```
TEXT="HIHIHI"

before-default: 
    echo "NEW BEFORE DEFAULT"
```

The new makefile will print:

```
NEW BEFORE DEFAULT
HIHIHI
AFTER DEFAULT
```

This example is a bit absurd it is not possible like this way, but I want to know if it is possible to make such Makefile composition close to this idea.

Comment: Your dependency chain is inverted.  The output will be printed in precisely the reverse order.  Because `before-default` depends on `default`, it will first run `default` before processing `before-default`.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, fixing it.

Comment: But now the first production is `before-default`, so just plain `make` will *only* run that. You want to invert the order of the rules so that `after-default` is the default target.

Answer (score 2):

Your example will be trivially fulfilled by adding `include A` at the start of `B`.  The new `before-default` target will override the old one.

```
vnix$ tail *
==> A <==
TEXT="AHAHA"

before-default: default
        echo "BEFORE DEFAULT"

default: after-default
        echo ${TEXT}

after-default:
        echo "AFTER DEFAULT"

==> B <==
include A

TEXT="HIHIHI"

before-default: default
        echo "NEW BEFORE DEFAULT"

vnix$ make -sf A
AFTER DEFAULT
AHAHA
BEFORE DEFAULT

vnix$ make -sf B
B:6: warning: overriding commands for target `before-default'
A:4: warning: ignoring old commands for target `before-default'
AFTER DEFAULT
HIHIHI
NEW BEFORE DEFAULT
```

This isn't a very good design, though; parametrizing things like you already do with `TEXT` comes with fewer surprises than having code that is being overridden elsewhere.

(See my comment above re: why the output is in the opposite order from what you were hoping.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

File `Makefile`:

```
# Define default TEXT
TEXT := HAHAHA

# Define default target
after:
    @echo AFTER

run:
    @echo $(TEXT)

before:
    @echo BEFORE

# Define dependencies
run: before
after: run

# Include the new makefile
include inheritance.mk
```

File `inheritance.mk`:

```
# Redefine TEXT
TEXT := HIHIHI

# Redefine before target
before:
    @ echo NEW BEFORE
```

When you run `make` **you'll have some warning** but it'll work as expected:

```
inheritance.mk:4: warning: overriding commands for target `before'
Makefile:10: warning: ignoring old commands for target `before'
NEW BEFORE
HIHIHI
AFTER
```